# Firebase Crash の設定で「Command not found」

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

FirebaseのCrash Reportingの機能を使いたいと思い、現在設定をしております。
クラッシュデータをFirebase consoleに表示させることはできたのですが、
シンボルファイルのアップロードの設定で困っています。お知恵をお貸しください。

プロジェクトフォルダ直下に「FirebaseCrash」フォルダを作成して以下のようにファイルを配置し、[Run Script]を設定しました。
公式サイト(https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files)
の手順ではpodを使用していますが、podが何かよく分からない為使用せず、パスを変更しています。

[image: FirebaseCrashフォルダ]

[image: Run Script]

ビルドすると「permission denied」と出たので、jsonファイルのパーミッションを644から744に変更したところ、今度は「Command not found」と出るようになりました。

[image: Command not found]

なんのことやらさっぱり分からずです。podを使用していないことが原因でしょうか？^^;
このエラーの回避策をお教え頂けますと大変助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebaseに関連するコマンドがインストールされていないようなので、とばしてしまったpodに関する作業を行うことで解決するように思えます。

以下のwebページ等を参考に設定してみてはいかがでしょうか。

https://cocoapods.org/
http://qiita.com/satoken0417/items/479bcdf91cff2634ffb1

Comment: CocoaPodsをインストール後、テストプロジェクトにpodfileを作成し`pod install`し、~.xcworkspaceを開く所までやってみました。
すると元のプロジェクトのビルドが通りました！助かりました！